# read.csv read csv file with function, cell wrapped with ="{value}"

Tags: r

I export my CSV file with python, numbers are wrapped as ="10000000000" in cells, for example:

```
name,price
"something expensive",="10000000000",
```

in order to display the number correctly, I prefer to wrap the big number or string of numbers(so someone could open it directly without reformating the column), like order ID into this format.

It's correct with excel or number, but when I import it with R by using read.csv, cells' values show as =10000000000.

Is there any solution to this? 
Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

how about:

```
yourcsv <- read.csv("yourcsv.csv")
yourcsv <- gsub("=", "", yourcsv$price)
```

Also, in my experience `read_csv()` from the `tidyverse` library reads data in much faster than `read.csv()` and I think also has more logic built into it for nonideal cases encountered, so maybe it's worth trying.